# Merge sort crashes when input size is sufficiently large

Tags: c++, debugging, mergesort

I have a series of growing input values that I want to analyze the runtime of.

```
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));  //initialize random num generator with time(NULL) as seed
    int size_arr[7] = {1000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000};
//  int size_arr[6] = {1000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 129992};
    int size = (sizeof(size_arr)/sizeof(int));
```

The input array `int size_arr[7]` works for my Quicksort and insertion sort implementations when passes an array created with the following:

```
for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){
            double sort_arr[size_arr[k]];
            for(unsigned int l = 0; l < (sizeof(sort_arr)/sizeof(double)); l++){
                sort_arr[l] = random_double(100.00, 1000.00);
            }
}
```

With the double values produced here:

```
double random_double(double min, double max){
    return (max - min) * ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) + min;
}
```

However, when I run the array through my merge sort function:

```
//merge sort algorithm
void merge_sort(double *A, int p, int r){

    if(p < r){                      //stopping condition
        int mid = floor((p + r) / 2);   //find array midpoint
        merge_sort(A, p, mid);      //recursively divide array
        merge_sort(A, mid+1, r);
//      merge(A, p, mid, r);        //merge (sort) sub-arrays
        merge_sort_merge(A, p, mid, r);
    }
}

void merge_sort_merge(double *A, int left, int mid, int right){
    double tmp[right];
    int l = left, m = mid+1, sort_index = left;
    for(int i = left; i <= right; i++){
        tmp[i] = A[i];
    }
    while(l <= mid && m <= right){
        if(tmp[l] <= tmp[m]){
            A[sort_index] = tmp[l];
            l++;
        }else{
            A[sort_index] = tmp[m];
            m++;
        }
        sort_index++;
    }
    while(l <= mid){
        A[sort_index] = tmp[l];
        sort_index++;
        l++;
    }
}
```

It crashes when the input size is exactly, 129992 (i've tested it with the `int size_arr[6]`).

The full code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <exception>

void merge_sort(double *A, int p, int r);
void merge(double *A, int p, int q, int r);
double random_double(double min, double max);

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));  //initialize random num generator with time(NULL) as seed
    int size_arr[7] = {1000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000};
//  int size_arr[6] = {1000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 129992};
    int size = (sizeof(size_arr)/sizeof(int));

    std::cout << "Merge Sort:" << std::endl;
        for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){
            double sort_arr[size_arr[k]];
            for(unsigned int l = 0; l < (sizeof(sort_arr)/sizeof(double)); l++){
                sort_arr[l] = random_double(100.00, 1000.00);
            }
            clock_t begin = clock();
            try{
                merge_sort(sort_arr, 0, (sizeof(sort_arr)/sizeof(double)));
            }catch(const std::runtime_error& re){
                std::cerr << "Runtime error: " << re.what() << std::endl;
            }catch(const std::exception &exc){
                std::cerr << exc.what();
            }catch(...){
                std::cerr << "Fuck" << std::endl;
            }
            clock_t end = clock();
            std::cout << "n = " << size_arr[k] << '\t' << (end - begin) << std::endl;
        }

    return 0;
}

//merge sort algorithm
void merge_sort(double *A, int p, int r){

    if(p < r){                      //stopping condition
        int mid = floor((p + r) / 2);   //find array midpoint
        merge_sort(A, p, mid);      //recursively divide array
        merge_sort(A, mid+1, r);
//      merge(A, p, mid, r);        //merge (sort) sub-arrays
        merge_sort_merge(A, p, mid, r);
    }
}

void merge_sort_merge(double *A, int left, int mid, int right){
    double tmp[right];
    int l = left, m = mid+1, sort_index = left;
    for(int i = left; i <= right; i++){
        tmp[i] = A[i];
    }
    while(l <= mid && m <= right){
        if(tmp[l] <= tmp[m]){
            A[sort_index] = tmp[l];
            l++;
        }else{
            A[sort_index] = tmp[m];
            m++;
        }
        sort_index++;
    }
    while(l <= mid){
        A[sort_index] = tmp[l];
        sort_index++;
        l++;
    }
}

double random_double(double min, double max){
    return (max - min) * ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) + min;
}
```

I've tried catching exceptions (it hasn't thrown any), using the VS JIT debugger but can't get any useful information out of it, the disassembly is as follows (arrow pointing to the fault):

```
00000000004100D0  cmp         rax,1000h  
00000000004100D6  ja          00000000004100BF  
00000000004100D8  sub         rcx,rax  
00000000004100DB  or          qword ptr [rcx],0 <---- 
00000000004100DF  pop         rax  
00000000004100E0  pop         rcx
```

It seems impossible to step through > 129k recursions, how do I narrow down where the problem is when I have such large input sizes?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, you are using VLA's like `double tmp[right];` these are not a standard c++ feature. Though I'd suspect these should fail with a stack overflow where `right` grows too large. Rather use a `std::vector<double>` or such.

Comment: I changed `double tmp[right]` to `std::vector<double> tmp(right)` and access it with `tmp[i] = A[i]`. It crashes before the first line prints

Comment: There are more of these beasts in your code.

Comment: Are you saying I should use vectors exclusively?  Eliminate arrays all together?  There is only one additional array in the `merge_sort_merge()` function.

Comment: _"Are you saying I should use vectors exclusively?"_ In favor of VLA's yes.

Comment: @corporateWhore Also, one huge advantage of using vector as opposed to VLA's is that you can use `vector::at()` to determine any out-of-bounds index you may be using.  With VLA's, you get no such help.  There was a question a few weeks ago where the OP was using VLA's, and using them hid a memory overwrite error and the code seemed to work.  Once changed to vector and using `at()`, the boundary access error was immediately detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `size_arr[k] == 129'992`, the size of

```
double sort_arr[size_arr[k]];
```

is `129'992 * sizeof(double) == 129'992 * 8 == 1'039'936`. This is just shy of `1'048'576 == 1M` (binary Mega).

The C standard does not say where [variable length arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) are stored (C++ does not define VLA at all), but typically they are allocated on the stack.

> using the VS JIT

Implies that you use windows. The default stack size on windows is [1MB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx). The 8640 bytes not used by `sort_arr` are easily exhausted by the rest of your program (mostly by `tmp` within `merge_sort_merge` which at the peak will be the size of `sort_arr`). In other words, you overflow the stack.

Solution: don't use variable length arrays for large arrays. (Don't use VLA at all if you prefer the program to be portable and standard compliant). Instead, use dynamically allocated arrays (`std::vector`).